# How to run a Litho animation automatically?

Tags: litho

What's the proper way to start a Litho animation when an Activity is first displayed.  All of the [Litho animation examples](https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/litho/animation) are initiated by a user action, but I want to run one automatically.

I tried to extend a Litho animation example [RTAnimationComponentSpec](https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/litho/animations/renderthread/RTAnimationComponentSpec.java) to fire the animation for the `@OnEvent(VisibleEvent.class)` instead of just `@OnEvent(ClickEvent.class)`.  But it didn't fire though.

Existing click event handler:

```
  @OnEvent(ClickEvent.class)
  static void onClick(ComponentContext c) {
    RTAnimationComponent.updateStateSync(c);
  }
```

Additional event handler that I added:

```
  @OnEvent(VisibleEvent.class)
  static void onVisible(ComponentContext c) {
    RTAnimationComponent.updateStateSync(c);
  }
```

I confirmed the `VisibleEvent` didn't fire by:

1. Loading the Render Thread example and confirmed the animation didn't start
2. Setting a breakpoint in the `onVisible()` method

How can I run a Litho animation automatically?

Comment: You likely didn't add the visibility event to a component. Add `.visibleHandler(ContinuousExampleComponent.onVisible(c))` to your root component in `@OnCreateLayout`

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found works is to make use of the [`@OnCreateInitialState`](https://fblitho.com/docs/state#initializing-a-state-value)

```
@OnCreateInitialState
static void createInitialState(
        ComponentContext c,
        StateValue<Boolean> state) {
    state.set(true);
}
```

This runs the animation, but I'm not sure if it's the preferred way.