# How to repeat a Litho animation

Tags: litho

The [Litho animation examples](https://github.com/facebook/litho/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/litho/animations) all begin when a user triggers an event.  But I need an animation that begins right away and continues indefinitely.  In other words, I have the same problem as [How to run a Litho animation automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975483/how-to-run-a-litho-animation-automatically) but I need a solution for Litho animations as opposed to basic Android animations.

Note, I asked a related question [How to run a Litho animation automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975483/why-doesnt-oneventvisibleevent-class-fire) when I tried to modify one of Litho's examples to initiate the animation without a user event.  But the question I'm asking now is how to repeat the animation once it's started?

Answer (score 2):

To start a Litho animation automatically and repeat it indefinitely, I modified [RTAnimationComponentSpec](https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/litho/animations/renderthread/RTAnimationComponentSpec.java) by starting a [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html):

```
@OnCreateInitialState
static void createInitialState(
        ComponentContext c) {
    startRepeatingAnimation(c);
}

static void startRepeatingAnimation(final ComponentContext c) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Repeat animation handler: about to scheduleAtFixedRate");
    TimerTask animateRepeat = new java.util.TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "Repeat animation handler: about to updateStateAsync");
                RTAnimationComponent.updateStateAsync(c);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Repeat animation handler: exception while animating: [" + e + "]");
            }
        }
    };
    new java.util.Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(animateRepeat, 0, FADE_IN_OUT_DURATION + FADE_IN_DELAY + FADE_IN_STAGGER_DELAY);
}

private static final String TAG = "RTComponentSpec";
```

I'm not sure this is a valid use of `createInitialState()` though.  According to the documentation, it's "To set an initial value for a state".  By state, Litho means [variables marked @State](https://fblitho.com/docs/state#initializing-a-state-value).  Informally, though, the animation is part of the state and the `TimerTask` does need to be started.  Semantically, initializing the `TimerTask` seems like it belongs to creating the initial state.

Empirically, the logs showed what I wanted.  The initial log message, "Repeat animation handler: about to scheduleAtFixedRate" appears once followed by periodic instances of "Repeat animation handler: about to updateStateAsync".

I suppose the solution might also work with other Android mechanisms for scheduling work on a periodic basis

Comment: You shouldn't start an animator in your @OnCreateInitialState method. This method is for initialising the state values, but the layout may not have been committed, so there may not be any views to animate.

Comment: A better place to start it would be in a VisibleEvent call back. e.g. https://github.com/facebook/litho/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/litho/java/animations/animationcookbook/ContinuousExampleComponentSpec.java#L72